# To show: In $\Bbb R^2$ there exists for every vector line $g$ a $c \in \Bbb R^{2*}$ with $g= \{x\in \Bbb R^2 :\langle c,x\rangle=0\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, orthogonality

Good day,

This is a question I had today for homework and firstly my main problem was that I didn't really understand the problem but this is what  I assume the question is asking. Imagine the line $g=\Bbb R v$ going through the origin and then there is the orthogonal vector $c$ sitting on any point on the line. Then you want to prove for an $x' = \lambda  v, x'$ being an element of $\Bbb R^2$ that $x=x'$?

I'm not sure if my thought process was correct. However taking it from there I am left a bit baffled how would you prove that $x=x'$? Is it possible to say that x is an element of $g$ and thus $x=x'= \lambda v$ and then taking it from there you just take any value for vector $c$ and then use that as a way of showing that it is orthogonal and that it is true for all $c$ in $\Bbb R^2$?

Hope I didn't confuse anyone and hopefully you guys could guide me through the problem and the solution.

Many thanks in advance for helping a college student :)

Comment: Hello :) Try $c:=\begin{bmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}v$ for given $v\in\mathbb R^2\setminus\{0\}$

Comment: The title of your question is the first thing that people see. If you realize that translating it i the body of the question is useful in an essentially English site, you'll agree that writing the title itself in English would have been a more reasonable approach...

Answer (score 0):

You're wrong. Let's take an example to understand what it is all about.

Let $v=(1,2)$. Then $\color{red}{g=\Bbb R v}$ is a straight line passing through the origin $0$, as you said.

$\color{red}g=\{\lambda (1,2): \lambda\in \Bbb R\}=\{(\lambda,2\lambda):\lambda \in \Bbb R\}= \{(\xi,2\xi):\xi \in \Bbb R\}=\{(\xi,\eta) \in \Bbb R^2: \eta=2\xi\}=\{(\xi,\eta)\in \Bbb R^2:2\xi+(-1)\eta=0\}=\{(\xi,\eta)\in \Bbb R^2:\langle \color{green}{(2,-1)},(\xi, \eta)\rangle=0\}=\{x\in \Bbb R^2:\langle \color{green}c,x \rangle=0\}$

with $\color{green}{c=(2,-1)}$

[image]